# Changing pages after a delay with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Unable to change change frames after a delay

> How can I use the showFrames method from logoPage class in the code provided below?

```
class temp(tk.Tk):


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "SOC_Workups")
    container_ = tk.Frame(self)

    container_.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = "True")
    container_.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    container_.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)


    self.frames = {}
    for F in (logoPage, mainPage):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(parent=container_, controller=self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame

        # put all of the pages in the same location;
        # the one on the top of the stacking order
        # will be the one that is visible.
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.showFrame("logoPage")



def showFrame(self, page):
    frame = self.frames[page]
    frame.tkraise()


class logoPage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    #label = tk.Label(self, text = "Start Page", font = LARGE_FONT)
    #label.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(self, height=500, width=1000)
    canvas.pack()

    logo = tk.PhotoImage(file='logo1.png')

    background_label = tk.Label(self, image=logo)
    background_label.image = logo
    background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    #parent.showFrame("mainPage")


class mainPage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, height=500, width=1000)
        canvas.pack()



app = temp()
app.mainloop()
```

> The app should start with logoPage and then changes to mainPage after 10 secs. I am unable to call the showFrame method from logoPage class.

Comment: you can call `controller.showPage(...)`. And you can use `app.after(10000, lambda:controller.showPage(...))` to run with 10000ms delay (10s).

Comment: next time when you edit question use button `{}` to format code and keep correct indentations.

Answer (score 1):

You have access to `showPage()` using `controller`

```
controller.showFrame("mainPage")
```

To run with delay you can use `root.after(millisecond, callback)`. In your code it will need `lambda` to create callback which runs function with arguments`

```
parent.after(10000, lambda:controller.showFrame("mainPage"))
```

---

**EDIT:** As Bryan Oakley said in comment you can run it without `lambda`

```
parent.after(10000, controller.showFrame, "mainPage")
```

Second argument in `after()` is `callback` - function's name without `()` - and all its arguments are as next arguments in `after()`

I changed it in code below too.

---

Full working code:

There is good rule in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which suggests to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - ie. `LogoPage`, `MainPage`, `Temp` similar to `Button`, `Frame`, `Button`, etc. it helps to recognize class in code. And some tools use speciala color for classes - see colors in code below.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Temp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "SOC_Workups")
        container_ = tk.Frame(self)

        container_.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = "True")
        container_.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container_.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)


        self.frames = {}
        for F in (LogoPage, MainPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container_, controller=self)

            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        print(self.frames)
        self.showFrame("LogoPage")

    def showFrame(self, page):
        frame = self.frames[page]
        frame.tkraise()


class LogoPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #label = tk.Label(self, text = "Start Page", font = LARGE_FONT)
        #label.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, height=500, width=1000)
        canvas.pack()

        logo = tk.PhotoImage(file='logo1.png')

        background_label = tk.Label(self, image=logo)
        background_label.image = logo
        background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        #parent.showFrame("mainPage")
        #parent.after(10000, lambda:controller.showFrame("MainPage"))
        parent.after(10000, controller.showFrame, "MainPage")


class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            canvas = tk.Canvas(self, height=500, width=1000)
            canvas.pack()

app = Temp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to use `lambda` here. You can pass args to `after` which results in slightly more readable code: `parent.after(10000, controller.showFrame, "mainPage")`